# Pyspark rdd to dataframe conversion

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to create a tempview spark with the following code but the issue is an error as below. I read some threads with similar problem which solved the problem by adding a spark session but it did not solve the issue for me. Any help would be appreciated.

The error:

```
    df = rdd.toDf(name_col1, name_col2)
AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'toDf'
```

The code:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('rates').setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

input1 = ('BTC','USD')
rdd = sc.parallelize([input1])
name_col1 = "fsym"
name_col2 = "tsyms"

df = rdd.toDf(name_col1, name_col2)
json_df = df.createTempView('payload')
```

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=rdd, schema=[name_col1, name_col2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alterntatively you can use `toDF` (note the capital F):

```
df = rdd.toDF([name_col1, name_col2])
```